# How to integrate Power Automate with BIM360

Tags: autodesk-forge, power-automate, autodesk-bim360, data-exchange

I am a Power Automate developer and I would like to pull the data from BIM360 and then save into Excel or SharePoint online. I want to pull the "Issue" from BIM360 as a start.

There is an article ([DOCS Help | Power Automate Connector for Data Exchanges | Autodesk](https://help.autodesk.com/view/DOCS/ENU/?guid=Power_Automate_Data_Exchanges)) . It mentioned an account administrator needs to install the Power Automate app from the App gallery. I have asked our admin and he said the App is enabled.

Then I start a Power Automate flow. I have no clue what to fill in for Data Exchange, Hub, Project and Top folder. When I press on each field, there is nothing prompt up. What can I try first?

[image]

I have read many article in FAQ but not very useful to me. Maybe because I am not BIM360 admin and most function is not available to me.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft also has a document about this connector. That doc provides a bit more details about the setup.

I would suggest to have a look at that doc:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/autodeskforgedataexc/

Answer (score 0):

This could be an issue with the integration between the ACC/BIM360 account and the Power Automate tool. Usually, this has to be done by you account admin. If you may have recently renewed your subscription you may want to reactivate the Power Automate app from the App Gallery and authorize access to BIM 360 document management. These details ideally should be coming right from the connected ACC/BIM360 account once Autodesk Data Exchange connector in Power Automate is enabled to work with your Data Exchanges. Kindly, confirm this with the account admin